# How to implement the injection principle similar to JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i want to create a parent interface like JpaRepository, then create a SimpleRepository implements the parent interface , when i start the jar, the SimpleRepository can inject the child interface like a interface extends JpaRepository.
Generally, we use JpaRepository :

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>
```

in my code:

```
public interface  CommonRepository<T,ID>
{
}

public class CommonSimpleRepository<T,ID> implements  CommonRepository<T,ID>
{
}

public interface UserRepository extends CommonRepository<User,Integer>
{
}
```

so, how can i inject the  CommonSimpleRepository<T,ID> to UserRepository?

Comment: You can replace CommonRepository with CommonSimpleRepository. because UserRepository inherit CommonRepository through CommonSimpleRepository.

Comment: you mean that i use userrepository as a class ?

Comment: could you provide more details on what exactly you want to implement? Probably some code snippets.

Comment: @谢茂林 did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public interface  CommonRepository<T,ID>
{
}

public class CommonSimpleRepository<T,ID> implements  CommonRepository<T,ID>
{
}

public interface UserRepository extends CommonSimpleRepository<User,Integer>
{
}
```